# What is a regex to use in Notepad++ to copy only the needed parts?

Tags: php, regex

I am using Notepad++ and I have a task to copy some attributes from a huge list as explained below:

this is just a tiny part of my list

```
[{"model_id":"58781","model_make_id":"mini","model_name":"Roadster","IntColors":[]}]
```

and I want to copy or leave only the `"58781",` and the `"mini",` and the `"Roadster",` and so on from the list.

So at the end my file (or the new one) will be

```
[{"58781","mini","Roadster",}]
```

of if it is easier leave the `:` also like     `[{:"58781",:"mini",:"Roadster",}]`

What regex should I use to do this?

Thank you

Comment: Please show some effort :-)

Comment: What you're starting with is valid JSON, and what you end up with isn't.  Is that intentional?  Anyway, rather than using a regexp, I would use a JSON parser (such as PHP's `json_decode`), grab the elements you desire from the data structure, and print them out in whatever format you like.

Comment: Why don't you want to leave the `[]`?

Comment: @DavidO Yes, my purpose is not to have a valid JSON at the end, I don't mind if it is not because I want to use it in somewhere else

Comment: @TimPietzcker Because I thought to replace it manually later with `(` for my purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this search/replace:

```
search: (?<=[{,])"[^"]+":|\[\]
replace: nothing
```